# Read RC File pyspark 2.0.0 from S3 with partitions

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rc

Is there a way that we can load RC Files with partitioned stored in S3 into pyspark Dataframe 2.0.0

Comment: This is one of the columnar file format that is used to store data. performs better compared to csv format

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a way to load RCFiles(from s3) to pyspark.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("elevateDailyJob").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1(col1 string,col2 string,col3 string,)PARTITIONED BY (DAYSERIAL_NUMERIC string) STORED AS RCFILE LOCATION 's3://my-databucket/my_file_rc/'")
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from table1")
```

the above can be run using spark-submit.
Note: you need to enable hivesupport for EMR version 5.x on wards(like I have done in 2nd line of the code.